# Hibernate statistics logging a query execution time

Tags: hibernate

I have setup hibernate logging statistics to get the query execution time and number of rows returned (e.g. HQL: Select p From Product p, time: 0ms, rows: 10) If the database is on a different server to the application, does the execution time include network transport latency or is it just the time executing the query on the database ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not clear from the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#statistics), checking the invocations of `org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor#queryExecuted` it becomes clear that they measure execution time on the application level (using `System.nanoTime()`) rather than pulling this information from the database. Based on this I think it is safe to assume that the network latency is included in the execution time.

Comment: Thanks Krisz, I was thinking the same but was looking for other people's thoughts.